# Animating individual letters of SKLabelNode

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I want to be able to animate the letters of `SKLabelNode`s individually, move them, change color, etc. Using SpriteKit how should I best achieve this? Should I just resort to creating the letters on individual `SKLabelNode`s? WIll that be scalable, eg. if I have thousands of words  for example would this begin to slow? I guess I should just test this myself but I was wondering before I do that is there a better approach that's completely different or should I just give up on trying to animate the letters individually? Perhaps it doesn't work in different languages or whatnot.

**edit** For the record I won't be animating them all at once, just plan on having them all in the same `SKNode` maybe I will only animate 50 at a time but it could vary.

Comment: Thousands of anything is potentially a performance issue. You can use either individual `SKLabelNode`'s or if you have image version of each letter, you can use `SKSpriteNode`. I haven't tested the performance of having a bunch of `SKLabelNode`s, but that's likely where you should start and work from there. Not hard to just try with an app you can add individual letters one at a time to get an idea of how many you can handle before performance degrades. Then dod the same with `SKSpriteNode`.

Comment: What do you want the letters to do? Depending on the situation you could assign physicsBody's to them and give them impulses and/or make them affected by gravity.

Answer (score 2):

If you are hoping to animate thousands of letters individually by having them each be a separate `SKLabelNode`, then yes, you will certainly run into frame rate issues. However, using many `SKLabelNode`s is probably the best way to do it. It's more lightweight than `SKSpriteNode` and can do everything you need it to (i.e. move, change color, and possibly rotate). When it comes to SpriteKit development, you can only think about scalability of animations to a certain extent--once you have enough individual sprites, the frame rate will inevitably drop.

But basically, yes, separate `SKLabelNode` is probably the best way.

Comment: For the record I won't be animating them all at once, just plan on having them all in the same `SKNode` I'm just gonna animate 50 at a time most likely, thanks for the answer, it seems to put me in the right direction. I will probably accept it later depending if anybody else has input

Comment: Thanks. And for the record, fifty will almost definitely be within the range to avoid a significant performance hit. Best of luck!